# Activating a radiobutton in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to enable a radiobutton apart from other controls. However I am getting an error at the point of creating a radio button. Please help.

**Controller:**

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"], function(Controller) {
    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App", {
        checkDone: function(oEvent) {
            var check = oEvent.getParameter("selected");
            if (check) {
                this.getView().byId("i1").setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                this.getView().byId("i1").setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }

    var oRB1 = new sap.ui.commons.RadioButton({
        text: 'yes',
        tooltip: 'Select for Yes',
        groupName: 'Group1',
        select: function() {
            alert('YES');
        }
    });

    );
});
```

**View**

```
<mvc1:View
   controllerName="sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App"
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:mvc1="sap.ui.core.mvc1">    
   <CheckBox id="ch1" text="Test" selected="false" select ="checkDone" enabled="true" />
   <Input  id="i1" enabled="false"></Input>
</mvc1:View>
```

Comment: learn the basics of sapui5

Comment: @santosh can you suggest me some course apart from the Open UI5 Walkthrough section?

Comment: @Jim As per the code you have not loaded the commons library. To know more about the basic of SAPUI5 you can go through  [SAPUI5: UI Development Toolkit for HTML](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic)

Comment: Also the I suggest to use `sap.m` library as `sap.ui.commons` is **deprecated** library

Comment: Also please read this before posting anymore to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Include the Commons library as well. Also I suggest to use `sap.m` library only because `sap.ui.commons` is deprecated library

```
<mvc1:View
   controllerName="sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App"
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns="sap.ui.commons"
   xmlns:mvc1="sap.ui.core.mvc1">    
   <CheckBox id="ch1" text="Test" selected="false" select ="checkDone" enabled="true" />
   <Input  id="i1" enabled="false"></Input>
</mvc1:View>
```

To start with SAPUI5 go through [SAPUI5: UI Development Toolkit for HTML5](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic)